# In a knockout.js foreach how to apply a specific class to an item on onClick

Tags: knockout.js

I have a koforeach binding which displays a serie of items based on an observable array populated via JSON. I would like to be able to change the class of the item div when I click on it. The idea is to use this list of item as a selector: the user choose one of the item by clicking on it.

The foreach is as follow:

```
<!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
    <div class="unselectedItem" data-bind="click: $parent.selectItem"><span data-bind="text: itemName"></span></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The call to the selectItem function in the ViewModel works perfectly but I don't succeed in correctly changing the class of the item that is clicked.

I can add an onCLick event on the div which changes the class when I click on one of the divs the first time but when I want to select another div I cannot remove the class of the first clicked div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways you can solve this problem.

**Here's a quick and dirty one:**

1. Add a `ko.observable` to your ViewModel to store the selected item
2. In your `selectItem` function, you update the observable with the new selection
3. Add a `css` binding to your items like so: `css: { 'selected' : $data === $parent.selectedItem() }`

Knockout creates a new observable for you because the css statement contains an observable. Every time `selectedItem` is updated, all css bindings will update.

Check out an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/snm8b9mr/

**Edit**: Just because I started my answer with *many different ways*, here's an alternative solution which I *personally* like better: https://jsfiddle.net/a45serz6/1/

It adds a `select` method and `selected` observable to all of your items. The logic that ensures there's only *one single selection at a time*, is managed someplace else. By using this approach, your data-binds will be a bit easier to read and write:

```
<li data-bind="css: {'selected': selected}, text: data, click: select"></li>
```